# MySQL trouble getting value from a third table in query

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help retrieving a value from a third table

```
product_attribute
| id_product_attribute | id_product | reference | ean13 |

product_attribute_combination
| id_attribute | id_product_attribute |

attribute_lang
| id_attribute | name |
```

I did the query below to get the product list, but I also want to get the `name` from attribute_lang and I don't know how.

Can anyone help me on this?

This is what I have now

```
SELECT T1.id_product, T1.reference, T2.name, T1.price, IF(LENGTH(TRIM(T1.ean13)) = 0, T1.id_product, T1.ean13) AS ean13
        FROM /*PREFIX*/product_attribute T1
        INNER JOIN /*PREFIX*/product_lang T2 ON (T1.id_product = T2.id_product AND T2.id_lang = /*CURRENT_LANGUAGE_ID*/) 
        WHERE T1.id_product /*PRODUCTS_ID_LIST*/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will need to add 2 more joins:

```
LEFT JOIN /*PREFIX*/product_attribute_combination T3 ON T3.id_product_attribute=T1.id_product_attribute
LEFT JOIN /*PREFIX*/attribute_lang T4 ON T4.id_attribute=T3.id_attribute
```

and add the T4.name as a selected column

The result will be something like this:

```
SELECT T1.id_product, T1.reference, T2.name, T1.price, IF(LENGTH(TRIM(T1.ean13)) = 0, T1.id_product, T1.ean13) AS ean13, T4.name
FROM /*PREFIX*/product_attribute T1
INNER JOIN /*PREFIX*/product_lang T2 ON (T1.id_product = T2.id_product AND T2.id_lang = /*CURRENT_LANGUAGE_ID*/)
LEFT JOIN /*PREFIX*/product_attribute_combination T3 ON T3.id_product_attribute=T1.id_product_attribute
LEFT JOIN /*PREFIX*/attribute_lang T4 ON T4.id_attribute=T3.id_attribute
WHERE T1.id_product /*PRODUCTS_ID_LIST*/
```